# Writing data for a few milliseconds to memcached

Tags: php, memcached

Please tell me how I can write data to memcached for a few milliseconds, I tried this, but it did not give any result

```
memcache_set($mem, 'block_users', 'ban', MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED, 0.5);
```

Comment: The last parameter *int $expire* will only accept whole seconds.  Why do you need it to be so short?

Comment: To limit the number of requests to 0.5 requests per second

Answer (score 0):

It impossible

```
expire - Expiration time of the item. A number of seconds starting from current time.
```

Use Redis, it takes milliseconds

```
# telnet 127.0.0.1 6379
set mykey Value PX 5000
+OK
PTTL mykey
:2135
PTTL mykey
:-2
```